# How to make function calls obey lexical scope in Python?

Tags: python

I want to make prevent an already defined function from looking up function names in the global scope, and instead to always call the versions available when the function was defined.

In the following snippet (http://ideone.com/GvghAy), `foo()` always looks up `add()` in the global scope, so when `add()` is replaced by `sub()`, `foo()` calls `sub()` instead. On the other hand, when `bar()` is defined, it captures a reference to the original `add()` function so calls to `bar()` will always call the original `add()`, even when `add()` is redefined.

```
from operator import add, sub

def foo(a, b):
    return add(a, b)

def create_bar_function():
    original_add = add
    def bar_function(a, b):
        return original_add(a, b)
    return bar_function

bar = create_bar_function()

print("foo before redefinition: " + str(foo(3, 4))) # 7
print("bar before redefinition: " + str(bar(3, 4))) # 7

# someone redefines add() with a different function
add = sub

print("foo after redefinition: " + str(foo(3, 4))) # -1
print("bar after redefinition: " + str(bar(3, 4))) # 7
```

Is it possible to create a function decorator such that the decorated function always captures references to the functions available when the decorated function was defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to pass it as an argument to the function.  It's not so bad though -- you can make it a keyword argument (which gets a default value "frozen" when the function is created):

```
def create_bar_function(add=add):
    ...
```

Please beware though -- Every python programmer that I know would consider this a serious hack.  It isn't something you really want to do.  Better is to avoid name clashes in the current namespace.  e.g. import `add` as a different name (or import the module):

```
from operator import add as _add
# import operator as op  # now use op.add ...
```

Now the user can define a new `add` and use `_add` when he/she wants `operator.add`.